# Android: launcher Activity is sometimes created in wrong ApplicationContext

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-context

The following code crashes in 0.01% of app launches on a few devices [see below].

```
public class MyApp extends Application {    
    private static MyApp app;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        app = this;
    }
    
    public static MyApp get(Activity ct) {
        if (null == app) {
            app = (MyApp) ct.getApplicationContext(); //java.lang.ClassCastException: context is not "MyApp".
        }
        return app;
    }
}
    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();       
        MyApp app = MyApp.get(this); //java.lang.ClassCastException
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.MyApp">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

According to user reviews, some crashes occur when ads are shown.
It could be that sometimes, `MyApp` is terminated while in background and `MainActivity` is re-created in a wrong `ApplicationContext` (maybe a web browser).

Is it possible to specify in `Manifest` that `MainActivity` may only be created in `MyApp` context?

**Edit**: This crash has occured mainly on `sdkInt` [28, 29, 30] and mainly on these devices:
[Samsung Galaxy M12, Samsung Galaxy A10s, Huawei P20 lite, Motorola Moto C Plus].

Here is one of stack traces:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4918)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4955)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute (ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2336)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8653)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at com.example.MyApp.get (MyApp.java:...)
  at com.example.MainActivity.onResume (MainActivity.java:...)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume (Instrumentation.java:1456)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:8353)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4908)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:4955)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute (ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:176)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2336)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8653)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Post the actual crash you're seeing, because your statement doesn't make any sense.  Applications are the root context of a running app.  There's only one per application.  You can't be run in some other application.  You can't run in some other app-  another app can launch your app via intent, but doing so launches your app.  I think you're just completely lost in what's happening.  Also, you're talking about AdActivity-  no such thing in the code you posted.

Comment: you will be using context when the application runs, no need to typecast to activity.

Remove activity argument, just return your static app context. You may check for null when using in background task.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to get application context. no need to typecast by taking the activity context which is giving ClassCastException

```
public class MyApp extends Application {    
        private static MyApp app;
    
        public MyApp() {
            app = this;
        }
    
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }
        
        public static MyApp get() {
            return app;
        }
    }
```

Inside your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();       
        MyApp app = MyApp.get(); // directly use the application context
    }
}
```